# Filter SQL results with 1 to many relationship

Tags: sql, join, common-table-expression, one-to-many, dbeaver

There are two tables, an account table and a tenant table. An account has multiple tenants. I want to find a list of accounts.
For eg, An account XXX can have multiple tenants - sandbox, implementation, development etc.
I want to extract a list of accounts without an implementation tenant, using SQL.

I tried the something like this :

```
    select a.accountname, t.tenanttype, 
    from account a 
    inner join tenant t
    using (accountid)
    WHERE
    t.tenanttype NOT IN ('Implementation%');
```

I get all accounts with their tenant types, but it just filters out the Implementation tenant , even though it exists.
Eg. An account XXX has 4 tenants, Sandbox. Dev, Implementation and Preview.
My code returns the account XXX, but with just three values - Sandbox, Dev, and Preview.

I want to get a list of accounts that don't have the Implementation tenant AT ALL.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your final statement it sounds like you need to use *not exists*, does the following work for you?

```
select a.accountname, t.tenanttype
from account a 
join tenant t on a.accountid = t.accountid
where not exists (
  select * from tenant t2
  where t2.accountid = t.accountid and t2.tenanttype like 'Implementation%'
);
```